# Mariadb import command line gives Invalid default value for 'date_time'

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am trying to import a mysql database from a mysql server to mariadb, i used mysqldump to create the file and the mariadb server gives this:

```
Invalid default value for 'date_time'
```

The sql mode is set to:

> ALLOW_INVALID_DATES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION

I'm not sure why it won't import since everything i have read says it's down to the sql mode.

it's complaining about this table creation:

```
CREATE TABLE `bid` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `auction_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_time` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `bid_amount` double DEFAULT '0',
  `bid_status` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'confirmed',
  `auction_price` double DEFAULT '0',
  `original_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_proxy` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `IDX_4AF2B3F3A76ED395` (`user_id`),
  KEY `IDX_4AF2B3F357B8F0DE` (`auction_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_4AF2B3F357B8F0DE` FOREIGN KEY (`auction_id`) REFERENCES `sale_auction` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_4AF2B3F3A76ED395` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `user` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1679 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;
```

It's this line:

```
`date_time` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
```

Comment: Your code works fine : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=1906be595881fb8acdebdb7ce5b3ce48

Comment: It doesn't work fine though, i get the error i stated. This is on a plesk server, but i edited my.cnf to set the msyql mode which then shows as it should when i query it so i'm confused

Comment: Please provide **complete and unchanged** error message, not a part of it. If shown part is complete error message displayed by your client software then obtain the error message in those form which MySQL server provides to the client. Also find the way to receive the SQL query which produces this error in strictly those form which was received by MySQL (general log, for example).

Comment: ERROR 1067 (42000) at line 15: Invalid default value for 'date_time' this is the error, it says line 15, which is the date_time field in the sql create statement i shared

Answer (score 0):

`CURRENT_TUMESTAMP` (or `NOW()` as synonym) as default value was introduced in MariaDB 10.0.

The error message indicates, that you try to import a dump into a MariaDB Server < 10.0. Upgrading to a more recent version should solve this issue.

The oldest supported MariaDB Version is 10.2, recent version is 10.6.